# issue when trying to build llvmcore at intrinsic generation

Tags: llvm

I am trying to compile the llvm 2336.11. I configured it with:

```
export CXX=/opt/local/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
export CC=/opt/local/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/mach/x86_64/ /usr/include/mach/x86_64
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/binutils/2.23.1/x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0/bin/ar /usr/bin/ar
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib /usr/bin/ranlib
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/nm /usr/bin/nm

../llvmgcc42-2336.11/llvmcore/configure --prefix=/Users/patrick.muscat/Documents/crosscompil/llvmbin/ --enable-assertions=no --enable-optimized=yes
```

But i get this:

```
llvm[1]: Building Intrinsics.gen.tmp from Intrinsics.td
/Users/patrick.muscat/Documents/crosscompil/llvmbuild/Release-Asserts/bin/tblgen: ERROR: Couldn't find the `Intrinsic' class!
make[1]: *** [/Users/patrick.muscat/Documents/crosscompil/llvmbuild/lib/VMCore/Release-Asserts/Intrinsics.gen.tmp] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/patrick.muscat/Documents/crosscompil/llvmbuild/lib/VMCore'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Then i modified the source to show the available definitions and classes adding Records.dump() in Record.cpp where the error text appears and i get this (empty):

```
------------- Classes -----------------
------------- Defs -----------------
```

Does anyone have an explaination ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found the solution. I installed the xcode command line tool that solves my problem.

I do not understand very well the influence of this installation... Apple document is quite osbcured sometimes...

Comment: can you provide scripts to build with XCode?